# Unable to remove python-pip package using apt

Tags: ubuntu, python, apt, pip

Here are my commands:

1. check if it exists

```sh
❯ sudo apt list python-pip       
Listing... Done
python-pip/cosmic,cosmic 9.0.1-2.3 all
```

2. remove it

```sh
❯ sudo apt remove python-pip 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'python-pip' is not installed, so not removed
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
```

I'm new to Linux. When I install Ubuntu distribution I found python command refers to v2.7, python3 refers to v3.6, and pip deals with python v2.7. What I want to do is to remove python and pip as they will haven't been mentained by the comming year, God willing!

So what is the problem I have?

Comment: I think this is related to Linux more than ubuntu.

Comment: While Ubuntu questions may get more knowledgeable attention at Ask Ubuntu, they are not off topic here @Ollie

Comment: @music2myear oh.  My mistake, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you actually have python-pip installed. The system is clearly stating python-pip is not installed. Just because a package is in the database (apt list) does not necessarily mean it is installed.

Comment: How to update these databases?

Comment: When you do an "apt update" it will get the latest package information from a mirror. If you later choose to install the package the newest one will be downloaded and installed. You can probably clear out your local copy if you had previously had it installed using an "apt purge python-pip" However, if the package is not actually installed there is little reason to worry about it being in the database.